# Subselects or something more elegant?

Tags: mysql, sql

It's difficult to explain what exatly i'm trying to do, so heres the query that allready works:

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(cars) '. HUGE_FROM_LIST .' '. HUGE_WHERE_QUERY .' AND cars > 0 ) AS cars,
(SELECT COUNT(houses) '. HUGE_FROM_LIST .' '. HUGE_WHERE_QUERY .' AND houses_type = 8 ) AS houses8,
...
```

This way i get two results, telling me how many cars and houses of type 8 there are. I dont wont to do one query for every result, so i tried subselects.

I do subselects, so the single querys only depend on their own WHERES.
Problem is that HUGE_FROM_LIST and HUGE_WHERE_QUERY are repeated every time and the whole thing gets really big.

Is there something more elegant?

Comment: Yes, break into two queries, and benchmark which method perform faster

Comment: yeah, thats not realy a more elegant way i search for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(IF(cars > 0, TRUE, NULL)) AS cars,
    COUNT(IF(houses_type = 8, TRUE, NULL)) AS houses8,
    ...
'. HUGE_FROM_LIST .'
'. HUGE_WHERE_QUERY
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you don't want to do multiple queries, but no matter how you do it... if you have `SELECT` criteria (logic) that will be repeated in many different places then it may be a good idea to encapsulate that logic into a single view. You can then simply refer to the view when you need to get at that data using that logic.

Comment: I should have mentioned, that i cannot use views here. This query is part of diffenten queries, which are triggered on some ajax refresh. So i want to have this as smooth as posible, cause there will be lots of ajax calls. If it cannot be condensed/optimized more then i will have to live with it.

Comment: Why does it being part of different queries discount the use of views?

Comment: It doesn't. But i cannot use them.

Comment: Again, the question becomes... why?

Comment: If i put it in a view i get a simpler access to it, but the performance /complexity of the query stays the same. So it's not a more elegant/faster query.